# How is 'Wie' (and the whole sentence) to be understood here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

So, I've just started reading my first German novel - 'Bretonische Brandung' by Jean-Luc Bannalec. The first paragraph of the novel reads as follows:

> **Wie** auf Zauberweise schwebten die flachen, lang gezogenen Inseln über
>   dem tiefopalen Meer, ein wenig verwischt, flimmernd. **Wie** eine Fata
>   Morgana lag der berühmte Archipel vor ihnen.

What part of speech is 'Wie' here grammar-wise? And what exactly is the meaning/impression the writer is trying to convey by using it here?
Please correct me if I'm wrong: it has here the simple meaning of 'like'? "Like in magic...", "Like a Fata Morgana..."?

Answer (score 4):

*Wie* comes in two flavours:

1. As *adverb*. This can either *ask* or *describe* for the "how" of an activity, like in "Wie hast du das gemacht?" or "Ich weiß, wie das geht". Typically translates to "how" in English. Not your case, though.
2. As *conjunction*, mainly for comparisons

   > Sie sieht aus wie Helena 
   >   Sie ist nicht so schön wie du
   >  
   >   Da geht es mir wie dir

The latter use typically translates to "like" or "as".

Comment: I'd call this a preposition rather than a conjunction.

Comment: @shuhalo You can, but then you are in conflict with most dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

**Wie** is a question word. But it has a second use as a comparision particle.

> Wie sieht dein neues Auto denn aus? - Wie das davor.

And yes, German *als/wie* roughly translate into English *as/like*. The rules when to use which one are a bit different though.

Answer (score 2):

Wie, in this context, can be translated as the [*simile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile) words, "as" or "like."

"*As* (if) in magic."

"*Like* Fata Morgana.

In other contexts, it means "how," but not in these.